# AngularJS Services - Exposing mutable state data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular factory, `Session`.
It exposes a method `join` that does some authentication stuff then off the back of that exposes an arbitrary resource through the same factory (code snippet below should illustrate).

Is there a best practice here in terms of exposing that property?
Solutions I see:

- Exposing getter methods
- Using a service rather than a factory and using `this`
- Doing something like this from a factory:

  ```
  // Public API
  var exports = {
      join: function(params, callback) {
             authenticate(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (!err) { 
                        exports.arbitraryResource = createArbitraryResource(data.resource); 
                    }
                    callback(err, data.sessionKey);
             });

      }
  };

  return exports;
  ```

Really interested to hear how other developers are exposing mutable properties from factories. I'd like to avoid getter methods if only because they're clunky to write and it *seems* like an anti pattern here.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a method getResource() which would make the authenticate call if resource was null else return the resource that had been setup by the previous call. This way the calling code does not care as to **how** the resource was fetched.

```js
app.factory('myService', function() {

  var resource = null;

  return {
    getResource: function(callback) {
      if (resource) {
        callback(null, resource);
      } else {
        authenticate(params, function(err, data) {
          resource = data
          callback(err, data);
        });

      }
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to have to pass in the parameters for the authentication every time I access the resource. The workflow should be 1. Call `join` once
2. Multiple consumers can now take advantage of `factory.arbitraryResource`

I think my question is more about how to expose mutable state from a factory whatever the use case, not so much 'how do i get this authentication API to work'

Comment: hmm.. well, in that case your approach is fine. It's just kind of old fashioned COM style API design that requires the client to maintain knowledge of previous call history.